# How to load just <head> content from AJAX data and replace with current <head>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using AJAX to get `<head>` content of data and want to replace with current  but it it keeps showing error and not working. The bottom code not working either

```
$('head').html($(data).find('head:first'));
```

Or

```
$('head').html($(data).find('head'));
```

Or

```
$('head').html($(data).find('head:first').html());
```

Comment: Are you trying to replace `<head>` content? any why `head:first`? Do you have more than one `<head>`?

Comment: @CesarBielich Yes i am trying to replace it with <head> content from ajax

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to replace head content then you would simply do

```
$('head').html(html);
```

With ajax it would be like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'get_data',
    success: function (data) {
        $('head').html(data);
    }
})
```

If you want to ensure to get the first `head` you could also use

```
$('head').first().html(data);
```

Comment: Yes!!! it works great!! i am wondering how it's work when i get fully data of other page and insert just <head> content??? why didn't i am not allow to use .find('head:first')); to ensure just get the head one??

Comment: It's not good practice to have more than one head in a page IMO so you would not have an issue if you only have more than one `head`